# copy one object to another

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection

.net 3.5, VS 2010... this is for an asp.net website.

I have an class called Agency.  there is a second class called Agency_Queries.  Agency_Queries inhertis the Agency class.  I'm trying to create a function that will copy the like properties in Agency to Agency_Queries.  I figured out how to do that.. but when i try to make it more generic so that i can pass in my class name and lists i'm doing something wrong.

So if there is an list(of Agency) that needs to be copied to list(of Agency_Queries) i've got something like the following.

```
  Dim AgencyS As List(Of Agency) = Nothing
    Dim Oc As New Agency_Controller
    AgencyS = Oc.GetAgencyData(0)

    Dim AgencyQueriesS As New List(Of Agency_Queries)
    Dim _itemProperties() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = AgencyS.Item(0).GetType.GetProperties()
    For Each item In AgencyS
        Dim X As NewAgency_Queries
        _itemProperties = item.GetType().GetProperties()
        For Each p As Reflection.PropertyInfo In _itemProperties
            For Each s As Reflection.PropertyInfo In X.GetType().GetProperties()
                If p.Name = s.Name Then
                    s.SetValue(X, p.GetValue(item, Nothing), Nothing)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        AgencyQueriesS.Add(X)
    Next
```

the problem is when i go to make this generic by the Dim X as new Agency_Queries.  How do i go about creating a new instance of the class in a generic sense.  I need to have it be a new instance or each time it gets added to teh AgencyQueriesS list all the objects have the same data values.

Here is the generic version... not working

```
 Shared Function CopyObject(ByVal inputList As Object, ByVal OutputClass As Object, ByVal outputList As Object) As Object
        Dim _itemProperties() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = inputList.Item(0).GetType.GetProperties()
        For Each item In inputList
            Dim oClean As Object = OutputClass
            For Each p As Reflection.PropertyInfo In _itemProperties
                For Each s As Reflection.PropertyInfo In oClean.GetType().GetProperties()
                    If p.Name = s.Name Then
                        s.SetValue(oClean, p.GetValue(item, Nothing), Nothing)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            outputList.Add(oClean)
        Next
        Return outputList
    End Function
```

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 3):

I took a little of this and that and came up with this:

```
    Imports System.Reflection

Public Class ObjectHelper

    ' Creates a copy of an object
    Public Shared Function GetCopy(Of SourceType As {Class, New})(ByVal Source As SourceType) As SourceType

        Dim ReturnValue As New SourceType
        Dim sourceProperties() As PropertyInfo = Source.GetType().GetProperties()

        For Each sourceProp As PropertyInfo In sourceProperties
            sourceProp.SetValue(ReturnValue, sourceProp.GetValue(Source, Nothing), Nothing)
        Next
        Return ReturnValue
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.. i tried the code and on the line in the for each loop, get the error message - Property set method not found.

Comment: "Property set method not found." Probably means you have a ReadOnly property.

Comment: Within your for each loop you need to check if the current property is read only and if it is then execute the SetValue line. So basically you need:

If sourceProp.CanWrite Then sourceProp.SetValue(ReturnValue, sourceProp.GetValue(Source, Nothing), Nothing)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub CopyPropertiesByName(Of T1, T2)(dest As T1, src As T2)

  Dim srcProps = src.GetType().GetProperties()
  Dim destProps = dest.GetType().GetProperties()

  For Each loSrcProp In srcProps
    If loSrcProp.CanRead Then
      Dim loDestProp = destProps.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = loSrcProp.Name)
      If loDestProp IsNot Nothing AndAlso loDestProp.CanWrite Then
        Dim loVal = loSrcProp.GetValue(src, Nothing)
        loDestProp.SetValue(dest, loVal, Nothing)
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```