# Duplicating a Non-Serializable (COM) Object

Tags: .net, vb.net, object, com, clone

I'm using VB.Net 2010. I want to duplicate the contents of a (COM) object entered to my application by an external (off-the-self) application. I wouldn't like to copy field & property values one by one (as fields/properties may be added or removed on future application builds).

**Object type is non-serializable.**

I've tried **Reflection** as follows (VB code suggested on thread [copy one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903188/copy-one-object-to-another/)):

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class ObjectHelper

    ' Creates a copy of an object
    Public Shared Function GetCopy(Of SourceType As {Class, New})(ByVal Source As SourceType) As SourceType

        Dim ReturnValue As New SourceType
        Dim sourceProperties() As PropertyInfo = Source.GetType().GetProperties()

        For Each sourceProp As PropertyInfo In sourceProperties
            sourceProp.SetValue(
                ReturnValue, 
                sourceProp.GetValue(Source, Nothing),
                Nothing)
        Next

        Return ReturnValue

    End Function

End Class
```

**That does not work, as the returned *sourceProperties()* array is empty.**

Any Ideas?

Comment: Copying the values one by one might not actually be such a bad idea. That way, you document that you thought about each and every property and convinced yourself that `dest.Prop1 = src.Prop1` is indeed the correct way to duplicate the property (as opposed to, for example, `dest.Prop1 = MakeDeepProp1Copy(src.Prop1)`.

Comment: Does your COM object support any of `IPersist` interfaces (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688695%28VS.85%29.aspx)? You can use that if it does.

Comment: I don't know VB.NET but doesn't `Source.GetType()` return `__COMObject`? What if you use VB.NET equivalent of `typeof<SourceType>` (according to Google, it should be `GetType(SourceType)`)?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, 1st of all, thanks for your responses. Regarding your 1st comment: How can I find out whether this object's class implements the *IPersist* interface?
*{ I did not code this class, nor do I have access to its code }*

Comment: Are you sure they're properties, or fields? If you add Dim fields As System.Reflection.FieldInfo() = Source.GetType().GetFields do you get any results?

Comment: If it can be cast to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile` then it supports it. Unfortunately, other IPersist* interfaces are not implemented there so you will have to import them from somewhere

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah, thanks for suggestion. I've tried it. An empty *fields* array is returned (i.e. Length = 0).

Comment: Thanks. Marked as the answer (referring to the 1st part, of how to fetch the properties).

Comment: But if the object you're copying is external, how do you know that it's public properties completely define its state? For example, it could have a public field and this code won't copy that. Or worse, it could easily have some internal state (private fields) that wouldn't get copied by this code. I think the only way to do this reliably is by a supported interface like IPersist as @ZdeslavVojkovic suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is a bug in the implementation

```
Dim sourceProperties() As PropertyInfo = Source.GetType().GetProperties()
```

should be

```
Dim sourceProperties() As PropertyInfo = GetType(SourceType).GetProperties()
```

`Source.GetType()` returns `_COMObject` type as that is the real type of your object, while you really want to check your interface type which is implemented by the object.

Other solution is to check whether the object implements any of [`IPersist` interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688695%28VS.85%29.aspx) and use that for real COM serialization. You can do that by casting the object to e.g. `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile`. Unfortunately, other IPersist* interfaces are not defined in that namespace so you will have to import them from somewhere.