# VB net copying classes and changing values

Tags: vb.net

I have a class defined, with many values defined in it. I want to make a copy of it and then change 1 variable. However when I do this it also changes the variable in my original class.

The code I'm using is shown below. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim NewClass As MyClass = PreviousClass(i)
NewClass.Value1 = NewVal
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking of Structure and not Class? Please show the Structure definition and how do you initialize the PreviousVar array

Comment: sorry it is a class

Comment: @Chris I see you changed to class, that is the whole purpose of class... It would work with structure.

Comment: A Structure variable is a Value Type, a Class variable is a Reference type. This means that when you assign a structure variable to another variable every data is copied in the assigned to variable and the two lives separately in memory. In classes only the reference is copied and thus, both variables see the same data

Comment: You may looking for deep copy of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be because when you `Dim` your `NewClass` object, this is simply creating another *reference* to the `PreviousClass` object. The variable names `NewClass` and `PreviousClass` therefore refer to exactly the same object, which is why `NewClass.Value1 = NewVal` also affects `PreviousClass`.

As JaydipJ suggests, you may need a deep copy of the object, these two answers look they might be useful for you -

[Create a “clone” of this object, not point to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574024/create-a-clone-of-this-object-not-point-to-it)

[copy one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903188/copy-one-object-to-another/)

Comment: Thanks the 'Create a “clone” of this object, not point to it' question solved it for me